# App Cordova Android - Firestore no reestablece conexion luego que el OS pone la app en modo Sleep

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Desarrolle una app con Cordova para Android y Firestore (v 4.12.1) para guardar documentos.
Luego que Android pone la app en modo Sleep, cuando vuelve a estar en primer plano nuevamente, no puedo leer o crear un documento en Firestore, aparentemente se pierde la conexion.
Si deshabilito en forma manual en el celular la conexion a Internet y luego la vuelvo a habilitar, vuelve a funcionar Firestore.
Alguien tiene idea por que ocurre esto y si hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la razón y tiene que ver que tenía el celular en modo de ahorro de batería, por lo visto en ese caso el OS no mantiene la conexion a Firestore.
Haré una nueva pregunta con el tag correspondiente, de como saber desde Cordova cuando Android esta en modo de ahorro.
Gracias. Saludos